# NGINX configuration in App Engine Flexible custom environment

Tags: java, nginx, google-app-engine

We have a Java/Spring Boot web application on Google App Engine Flexible environment.  One of the endpoints is for file uploads and often times, NGINX is buffering these requests to disk:  a client request body is buffered to a temporary file /var/cache/nginx/client_temp/0000000001.

I'm having trouble determining where the NGINX configuration is in this case.  So far I've tried different approaches via the Dockerfile.  How do I configure NGINX or provide a nginx.conf file in Google App Engine Flexible?  Listing my Dockerfile and nginx.conf file specifying the client_body_buffer_size.

Dockerfile:

```dockerfile
FROM openjdk:8
VOLUME /tmp
ARG JAR_FILE=target/user-app.jar
COPY ${JAR_FILE} app.jar
COPY config/nginx/nginx.conf /etc/nginx/nginx.conf

# create log dir configured in nginx.conf
RUN mkdir -p /var/log/app_engine

# Create a simple file to handle heath checks. Health checking can be disabled
# in app.yaml, but is highly recommended. Google App Engine will send an HTTP
# request to /_ah/health and any 2xx or 404 response is considered healthy.
# Because 404 responses are considered healthy, this could actually be left
# out as nginx will return 404 if the file isn't found. However, it is better
# to be explicit.
RUN mkdir -p /usr/share/nginx/www/_ah && \
    echo "healthy" > /usr/share/nginx/www/_ah/health

ARG SPRING_PROFILES_ACTIVE

ENV SPRING_PROFILES_ACTIVE=$SPRING_PROFILES_ACTIVE

ENTRYPOINT ["java","-jar","/app.jar"]
```

nginx.conf:

```nginxconf
events {
    worker_connections 768;
}

http {
    sendfile on;
    tcp_nopush on;
    tcp_nodelay on;
    keepalive_timeout 65;
    types_hash_max_size 2048;
    include /etc/nginx/mime.types;
    default_type application/octet-stream;
    client_body_buffer_size 500M;

    # Logs will appear on the Google Developer's Console when logged to this
    # directory.
    access_log /var/log/app_engine/app.log;
    error_log /var/log/app_engine/app.log;

    gzip on;
    gzip_disable "msie6";

    server {
        # Google App Engine expects the runtime to serve HTTP traffic from
        # port 8080.
        listen 8080;
    }
}
```